# Java ssl certificate issue

Tags: java, ssl-certificate, restful-url

I'm trying to access from local host to access this https site.s url:

```
​public  static void main(String a[]) { 
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); 
            String desc = "Test comments updates"
  String url_1="https://site.s:port/gdhsbsbe";
            restTemplate.put(url_1, desc);
            System.out.println("finished"); 
}
```

I got this exception:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching site.s found.
```

Any suggestions how to avoid it? Is there any way of getting certificate within program.

Comment: you need to give proper URL of the site i.e proper domain name and port

Comment: `site.s` is not a real domain name, and `port` is not a port number. Or, if `site.s` really is a domain name, the certificate it sent doesn't contain it.

Comment: this https://site.s:port/ is an example

Comment: what I want to convey is this is how URL looks like..a sample..now while accessing from local to this domain, I'm getting certificate error